How can I prevent a negative floating number to be automatically changed in ruamel.yaml
I read a yaml-file with couple of floating numbers:
neg_number: -2.32870E+00
pos_number: 0.14618E+01

If I dump these numbers I get:
neg_number: -0.23287E+01
pos_number: 0.14618E+01

There is no change of positive number but a change of negative number.
Is there any way how to prevent this behaviour of negative numbers?
P.S.: ruamel.yaml version 0.18.6
here is my code:
  from ruamel import yaml
  yaml2 = yaml.YAML()
  yaml2.width = 9999    
  yaml2.preserve_quotes = True
  yaml2.indent(offset=4, sequence=4, mapping=4)

  with open('test3.yaml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        pa = yaml2.load(f)
  
  with open('datadump.yaml', 'w') as file:
         yaml2.dump(pa, file)


This is still the same number, just written a bit differently. Do you mean to impose the format of the floats?

yes, the number is the same, but what i want is that the number (decimal point) stays same after dump
same behaviour as with positive number (why there is no change with positive number?)

Probably because it already was written with the same format you get for your outputs. Why exactly is the way your floats are written important?

@bk_ing From the manual: "It is best to always have sequence >= offset + 2 but this is not enforced. Depending on your structure, not following this advice might lead to invalid output." Do you have any reason not to follow that advice? The offset indicates where the dash is positioned within the indentation for sequence (defaults: sequence=2, offset=0), given that your offset=4, sequence=4 makes no sense at all.

You should always include a minimal program that reproduces your problem, so
we know what you are doing.
You can try to run this:
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
neg_number: -2.32870E+00
pos_number: 0.14618E+01
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

which gives:
neg_number: -2.32870E+00
pos_number: 0.14618E+01


thanks for your answer and sorry for missed code, i attached it in my original post

thanks @anthon
I ran you code and the result was as yours
If you change for example the number 2 in that  negative number to 0 (from -2.32870E+00 to -0.32870E+00) then you'll see that the dumped neg_number changed without any reason

It looks like the dumping code doesn't properly work with leading zeros in combination with negative floats.
